# strange premature validation of control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am learning a newly created default simple MVC4 web project.

In the index page, I have a link for the user to log on the site with his account. After that he will be redirected to a form to enter new name, new password.

I have this form ready for validation using `[Required]`. But as sooon as the redirected page is completely loaded, these controls (username and password) were done validated (`Field needs be filled in`) too.

Here is the code of POST after the user log in with his account

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
{
    return RedirectToCreateUser(returnUrl);
}

// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
return View(model);
```

and here is the method RedirectToCreateUser

```
private ActionResult RedirectToCreateUser(string url)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(url))
    {
        return Redirect(url);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CreateNewUser", "Account");
    }
}
```

finally the CreateNewUser method which is for http GET

```
public ActionResult CreateNewUser(CreateNewUserModel model)
{         
    return View(model);
}
```

and another one for http POST which I think hasn't been accessed yet though.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNewUser(CreateNewUserModel model, string url)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, null, true);
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
            return RedirectToAction("CreateUserSuccess", "Account");
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is here

finally the CreateNewUser method which is for http **GET**

```
public ActionResult CreateNewUser(CreateNewUserModel model)
{         
    return View(model);
}
```

You cannot pass an object as a parameter on a get request.  Probably that signature should be

```
public ActionResult CreateNewUser()
{    
    var model = new CreateNewUserModel();     
    return View(model);
}
```

or something similar

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateNewUser` action is firing on the `[HttpPost]` and attempting to post with invalid (empty) credentials.

You need to add something to this effect using `[HttpGet]`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateNewUser(CreateNewUserModel model)
{         
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think without `[httpx]` the method is supposed to be a GET one by default